# Ordenação de vetor e matriz

Tags: c, matriz, array

Tem outro método para ordenar vetor / matriz em ordem crescente ou decrescente sem ser o que eu utilizei ? ( O que tu mudaria nesse código pra deixar ele " melhor " ? )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ordem (int vetor[], int tamanho);

int main ( void ) {

    int tamanho, *vetor;

    printf("\nInforme o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%i",&tamanho);

    vetor = (int *) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));

    for ( int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){

        printf("\nInforme o valor %i: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i",&vetor[i]);

    }

    ordem (vetor, tamanho);

    puts("\n-----------------------------");

    for ( int p = 0; p < tamanho; p++){
        printf("\n%i ",vetor[p]);
    } puts("");

    free(vetor);

    return 0;
}

void ordem (int vetor[], int tamanho){

    int cache = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){

        for ( int h = i + 1; h < tamanho; h++){

            if (vetor[i] > vetor[h]){

                cache = vetor[i];

                vetor[i] = vetor[h];

                vetor[h] = cache;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: O problema é justamente que existem inúmeros. DÊ uma olhada em [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pesquise um pouco sobre [Algorítimos de ordenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Não existe o 'mais eficiente', o quão bom ele é depende muito do vetor que você vai ordenar. O que você utilizou é o Bubble Sort, geralmente é o primeiro algorítimo de ordenação apresentado a estudantes. Um algorítimo que é (muito) eficiente é o [Quick Sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), ele basicamente divide o vetor de forma recursiva, fazendo assim, a mesma tarefa de organização de forma mais rápida.

Comment: Vlw, vou dar uma pesquisada.

Comment: Só um adendo, dê uma olhada na função [`qsort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qsort) da `stdlib.h`. Essa é uma implementação padrão do Quick Sort, nem de longe a mais rápida implementação possível, mas é robusta e fácil de usar.